# Android layout title bar is not visible

Tags: android, xml, layout, titlebar

I have created xml layout file. And when I give it as content to my Activity the TITLE BAR IS NOT VISIBLE. How can I make it visible. I tried to use setTitle("Title");

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN); 
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras(); 
int layoutId = b.getInt("layout");
Log.d("====>>>", " " + layoutId);
setContentView(layoutId); 
setTitle("Title"); 
}
```

function in onCreate() method. I is not work. This is my xml file.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.universityapp.enrollee.FacultyInformationActivity"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    >

     <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="@string/text_faculty_information_agro"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I start activity via ListView:

```
 profListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    facultyInfoIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), FacultyInformationActivity.class);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putInt("layout", facultyLayoutNames[position]);
                    facultyInfoIntent.putExtras(b);
                    startActivity(facultyInfoIntent);
            }

            Log.d("Selected faculty", facultiNames[position]);
        }
    });
```

This is my Manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.universityapp.universityapp" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name="com.universityapp.common.MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.universityapp.common.MenuActivity"
            android:label="Главное меню" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.universityapp.enrollee.ContacsActivity"
            android:label="Наши контакты" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.universityapp.enrollee.Map"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_map" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.universityapp.enrollee.MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.universityapp.bachelor.PlatonusActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_platonus" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.universityapp.database.DatabaseActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_database" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.universityapp.enrollee.EnrUniversityInfo"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_enr_university_info" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.universityapp.enrollee.ProfessionsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_professions" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.universityapp.enrollee.FacultyInformationActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_faculty_information" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: you can't see the title bar or the title in the title bar?

Comment: I cant see the title bar

Comment: post your manifest.xml

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer This is my manifest

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer! I have changed Activity to ActionBarActivity and it works!

Comment: AppCompatActivity also works for me (where applicable).

Answer (score 18):

Change:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

}
```

in your class file to:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To show the title bar you can use this in your `onCreate`:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: Not working: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        int layoutId = b.getInt("layout");
        Log.d("====>>>", " " + layoutId);
        setContentView(layoutId);
        setTitle("Title");
    }

Comment: @Makko yes in this place, try and tell me the results

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by doing this (as [suggested by HafizWaleedHussain](https://tagmycode.com/snippet/1059/android-hide-and-show-android-title-bar#.VSCjtVzNpXs)):

```
public void showTitle() {
            try {
                    ((View) findViewById(android.R.id.title).getParent())
                                    .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            getWindow().addFlags(
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
```

If this didn't work then open your Android Manifest file and remove this line if it exist:

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

Answer (score 1):

Got o styles.xml and make a new style

```
<style name="CustomWindowTitleBackground">
        <item name="android:background">#323331</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
     </style>
```

and call it from Manifest (You can also add other features inside item tags)

```
 <activity
            android:name=".st.activity.MyGoogleMap"
            android:theme="@style/CustomWindowTitleBackground">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I removed the statement android:theme="@style/AppTheme" in the application tag and the bar started appearing

   <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        **android:theme="@style/AppTheme"**>
```